# How to insert new value autonumber by parameters to access

Tags: sql, ms-access, autonumber

When I press insert, I receive the error: `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement`

- `EmployeeID` (Autonumber)
- `EmployeeName`(Text)
- `Position`(Text)
- `Address`(Text)

  ```
  OleDbDataAdapter ad;
  DataSet ds;
  DataTable dt;

  protected void SetInsertParameters()
  {
      string sql = "INSERT INTO Employee(EmployeeName,Position,Address)"+
                   " VALUES (@EmployeeName,@Position,@Address)";
      ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);


      OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter("@EmployeeName", OleDbType.VarChar);
      param.SourceColumn = "EmployeeName";
      param.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
      ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

      param = new OleDbParameter("@Position", OleDbType.VarChar);
      param.SourceColumn = "Position";
      param.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
      ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

      param = new OleDbParameter("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar);
      param.SourceColumn = "Address";
      param.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
      ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
  }


  void InsertNewValues()
  {
      dt = ds.Tables["Employee"];
      DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
      row[0] = txt_employeeID.Text;
      row[1] = txt_name.Text;
      row[2] = txt_position.Text;
      row[3] = txt_address.Text;
      dt.Rows.Add(row);
      ad.Update(ds, "Employee");
      ad.Fill(ds);

  }
  ```

Comment: Have you named your columns in your table? I don't see it here.

Comment: The other thing is that you are probably using a 'CommandType.Text` which I don't believe is compatible with this type of insert. Its used for `.TableDirect` or `.StoredProcedure`

Answer (score 0):

Position is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266?wa=wsignin1.0) and must be bracketed:

```
 "INSERT INTO Employee(EmployeeName,[Position],Address)"
```